# ruby - how to dynamically call instance method in a module

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to dynamically call instance methods. I found `send`, `call`, `eval` to do that. There are examples of dynamically calling class methods, but I haven't figured out how to make it work for instance methods.

e.g.

```
module MyModule
  def Foo
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

the instance method names can be listed by:

```
MyModule.instance_methods
#=> [:Foo]
```

But I can't figure out how to call the method:

```
MyModule.send("Foo")
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `Foo' for MyModule:Module

MyModule.method("Foo").call
#=> NameError: undefined method `Foo' for class `Module'

eval 'MyModule.Foo'
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `Foo' for MyModule:Module
```

How can I call the instance methods, like `Foo`, by the method name?

Comment: Note that `eval 'MyModule.Foo'` is the same as `MyModule.Foo`.

Comment: It's an *instance method*. You need an instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: Bad practice and it makes little to no sense:

```
MyModule.instance_method(:Foo) # #<UnboundMethod: MyModule#Foo>
        .bind(Object)          # #<Method: MyModule#Foo>
        .call                  #=> hello
```

You can't call an unbound method, thus you have to first bind it to some object.

References:

- [Module#`instance_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-instance_method)
- [UnboundMethod#`bind`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind)
- [Method#`call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Method.html#method-i-call)

---

It would be much easier if you make the method singleton method:

```
module MyModule
  def self.Foo
    puts "hello"
  end
end

MyModule.Foo
#=> "hello"
```

Another option is to use [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function) (read up on the method's visibility for the including object when using this option):

```
module MyModule
  def Foo
    puts "hello"
  end
  module_function :Foo
end

MyModule.Foo
#=> "hello"
```

And yet another one is using `extend self`:

```
module MyModule
  def Foo
    puts "hello"
  end

  extend self
end

MyModule.Foo
#=> "hello"
```

P.S. It is not conventional to use capital letters in method names. It is very rare case in Ruby where it can be used and your case is *100% not* the one :)

Comment: Both `module_function` and `extend self` are worth to mention here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the singleton method approach works for me!

Comment: Without module body editing `Class.new.include(MyModule).new.Foo` just as ugly but still possible way.

Comment: @Ilya you don't have to create a class: `Object.new.extend(MyModule).Foo`

Comment: @Stefan `Object.extend(MyModule).Foo` is even shorter (despite the pollution caused by it) :)

Comment: @Stefan, yes, it's a little bit simple, but still too complex to call just a method :)